# How can set the preferred_language in the form processor?

Tags: form-processor

Is it possible in the form-processor extension to set the preferred_language field when creating contacts? I can't find a way

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see this is not possible at the moment, but can be added to the create individual action fairly easily. Are you in a position to do that yourself or possibly fund the change?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll investigate and try to improve the extension.

Comment: The actual actions are in the extension action-provider. You will need to change the action CreateIndividual which will probably be in folder .....Civi/Actions/Contact in the extension